# RegionIntersection between a Hyperplane and a 3D solid

Tags: regions, opencascade

```
SeedRandom[1];
ℛ = 
  RandomPolyhedron[{"ConvexHull", 12}, 
   DataRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}];

Through[{RegionQ, RegionDimension, 
     RegionEmbeddingDimension}[#]] & /@ {ℛ, 
  Cylinder[{{-5, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}}, 2], Hyperplane[{1, 0, 0}, -1]}
```

> {{True,3,3},{True,3,3},{True,2,3}}

```
Show[
Region[Style[ℛ,Cyan], Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
,Region[Style[Cylinder[{{-5,0,0},{5,0,0}},2],Green]]
,Region[Style[Hyperplane[{1, 0, 0}, -1],Red]]
]
```

[image]

I can find the `RegionIntersection` between the `Hyperplane` and the cylinder.

```
RegionIntersection[Cylinder[{{-5, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}}, 2], 
  Hyperplane[{1, 0, 0}, -1]] // Region
```

**Question**

How do I do the following using `Region*` functions?

```
RegionIntersection[ℛ, 
  Hyperplane[{1, 0, 0}, -1]] // Region
```

---

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- We add `PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}` to the `Hyperplane`.
- We use `OpenCascadeLink` to do the intersection of two surfaces.

```
SeedRandom[1];
ℛ = 
  RandomPolyhedron[{"ConvexHull", 12}, 
   DataRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}];

Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
plane = Hyperplane[{1, 0, 0}, -1];
shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[ℛ];
shape2 = 
  OpenCascadeShape[
   ToBoundaryMesh@
    DiscretizeGraphics[plane, 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]];
mesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[
   OpenCascadeShapeIntersection[shape1, shape2]];
reg=MeshRegion[mesh];
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.2], ℛ, Cyan, 
   plane}, {FaceForm[Red], reg}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- If we only want to draw the intersection,we can also use

```
(* Version 12,13,14 *)
SeedRandom[1];
ℛ = 
  RandomPolyhedron[{"ConvexHull", 12}, 
   DataRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}];
regm = RegionMember[ℛ];
Show[ContourPlot3D[{1, 0, 0} . {x, y, z} == -1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 
   5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, regm@{x, y, z}], 
  RegionBoundaryStyle -> None], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[.2], ℛ}], Boxed -> False]
```

```
(* Version 13 or Version 14 *)
Show[ContourPlot3D[{1, 0, 0} . {x, y, z} == -1, {x, y, 
    z} ∈ ℛ, RegionBoundaryStyle -> None], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[.2], ℛ}],Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Lots to explore and learn. Thanks @cvgmt. The last figure does not show proper opacity on v12.2.0.

Comment: @Syed updated the code which work for  Version 12.2.